# garbage collect objects after lazy values have been calculated

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, lazy-evaluation

in my current project I am processing a quite big amount of data and the processing of the data should be both memory efficient and computationally performant.
Every item has some meta-data that can be read very fast and is almost always interesting. Additionally to that every item has the actual data that is comparatively rarely read but the reading and especially the parsing is very time consuming. Therefore it seams natural that the parsing of the data should only be done if it is actually requested.

For that purpose I was thinking of lazy values:

```
class Item(metaData: MetaData, dataString: String) {
    lazy val data = parse(dataString)
}
```

Now the data is only parsed if it is actually requested. The problem is now, that the dataString and the parsed data is kept in memory. As far as I can see, "dataString" cannot be accessed anymore as soon as "data" has been called (or is there?) and it can therefore be garbage collected. Unfortunately this seams not to happend.

Is there a way to solve the problem in a different way or to give the garbage collector a hint to garbage collect the dataString here?

Comment: not sure though.. try `class Item(metaData: MetaData,val dataString: String)` if it works..

Comment: This will certainly not work because `dataString` is a public field of `Item` then.

Comment: well.. its because you'll have the instance of `dataString` in your class..you can also try `class Item(metaData: String, private val dataString: String)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need a little bit more tooling:

```
class Item(dataString: String) {
  private var storedData = dataString
  lazy val data = {
    val temp = parse(storedData)
    storedData = null
    temp
  }
}
```

An extra reference to `dataString` is not kept because you never refer to it outside of the constructor (which sets `storedData`), and the reference you store in `storedData` is nulled out once you use it, so the string is then free to be GCed.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it is never garbage collected is because Scala stores `dataString` in a private field so the lazy function can later be evaluated, so it holds onto `dataString` forever. If the lazy evaluation happened in a separate closure, this wouldn't be a problem, but it is just a plain class method, so `dataString` is held as long as the class instance is.

You can see this by compiling and disassembling the class.

```
class Item(dataString: String) {
    lazy val data = parse(dataString)


    def parse(s: String) = s.reverse

}
```

As the disassembly shows, a final private field `dataString` is created which is stored in the constructor. Lazy evaluation occurs in the method `data$lzycompute` which takes the value `dataString`, performs the computation on it, and stores the result in the `data` field. But `dataString` still holds its original value.

It also defines a field `bitmap$0` to keep track of whether the lazy function has been evaluated or not, and a wrapper accessor member also called `data` which calls the function if necessary and then returns the field `data`.

```
.version 50 0
.class super public Item
.super java/lang/Object
.runtimevisible annotation Lscala/reflect/ScalaSignature;
    bytes =  string [_7]
.end annotation
.attribute ScalaSig '\x05\x00\x00'

.field final private dataString Ljava/lang/String;
.field private data Ljava/lang/String;
.field volatile private bitmap$0 Z

.method private data$lzycompute : ()Ljava/lang/String;
    .limit stack 3
    .limit locals 2
    .catch [0] from L4 to L34 using L46
    aload_0
    dup
    astore_1
    monitorenter
L4:
    aload_0
    getfield Item bitmap$0 Z
    ifne L28
    aload_0
    aload_0
    aload_0
    getfield Item dataString Ljava/lang/String;
    invokevirtual Item parse (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    putfield Item data Ljava/lang/String;
    aload_0
    iconst_1
    putfield Item bitmap$0 Z
L28:
.stack append
    locals Object Item
.end stack
    getstatic scala/runtime/BoxedUnit UNIT Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
    pop
    aload_1
    monitorexit
L34:
    aload_0
    aconst_null
    pop
    aconst_null
    putfield Item dataString Ljava/lang/String;
    aload_0
    getfield Item data Ljava/lang/String;
    areturn
L46:
.stack same_locals_1_stack_item
    stack Object java/lang/Throwable
.end stack
    aload_1
    monitorexit
    athrow
.end method

.method public data : ()Ljava/lang/String;
    .limit stack 1
    .limit locals 1
    aload_0
    getfield Item bitmap$0 Z
    ifeq L14
    aload_0
    getfield Item data Ljava/lang/String;
    goto L18
L14:
.stack same
    aload_0
    invokespecial Item data$lzycompute ()Ljava/lang/String;
L18:
.stack same_locals_1_stack_item
    stack Object java/lang/String
.end stack
    areturn
.end method

.method public parse : (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    .limit stack 4
    .limit locals 2
    new scala/collection/immutable/StringOps
    dup
    getstatic scala/Predef$ MODULE$ Lscala/Predef$;
    aload_1
    invokevirtual scala/Predef$ augmentString (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    invokespecial scala/collection/immutable/StringOps <init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    invokeinterface scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized reverse ()Ljava/lang/Object; 1
    checkcast java/lang/String
    areturn
.end method

.method public <init> : (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit stack 2
    .limit locals 2
    aload_0
    aload_1
    putfield Item dataString Ljava/lang/String;
    aload_0
    invokespecial java/lang/Object <init> ()V
    return
.end method

.const [_7] = Utf8 '\x06\x01)2A!\x01\x02\x01\x0b\t!\x11\n^3n\x15\x05\x19\x11a\x02\x1ff[B$\x18PP\x02\x01\'\t\x01a\x01\x05\x02\x08\x195\t\x01B\x03\x02\n\x15\x05!A.\x198h\x15\x05Y\x11\x01\x026bm\x06L!!\x04\x05\x03\r=\x13\'.Z2u\x11!y\x01A!A!\x02\x13\x01\x12A\x033bi\x06\x1cFO]5oOB\x11\x11c\x06\x08\x03%Ui\x11a\x05\x06\x02)\x05)1oY1mC&\x11acE\x01\x07!J,G-\x1a4\n\x05aI"AB*ue&twM\x03\x02\x17\'!)1\x04\x01C\x019\x051A(\x1b8jiz""!H\x10\x11\x05y\x01Q"\x01\x02\t\x0b=Q\x02\x19\x01\t\t\x11\x05\x02\x01R1A\x05\x02\t\nA\x01Z1uCV\t\x01\x03\x03\x05%\x01!\x05\t\x15)\x03\x11\x03\x15!\x17\r^1!\x11\x151\x03\x01"\x01(\x03\x15\x01\x18M]:f)\t\x01\x02\x06C\x03*K\x01\x07\x01#A\x01t\x01'
```